# How to access the Twitter Streaming API from Python

Tags: python, twitter, twitter-streaming-api

I am looking to do some twitter programming using Python.  I am currently using the excellent Python Twitter Tool by Sixohsix.  I can post tweets from my app to my bot accounts feed but currently can't retrieve the Twitter Streaming API.  Here is my code:

```
    creds = connect.createCredsDict()

    t = TwitterStream(auth=OAuth(creds['accessToken'],
                      creds['accessTokenSecret'],
                      creds['conKey'],
                      creds['conSecret']))

    for msg in t.user():
        print msg['direct_message']['text']
```

I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

For those of you who don't know the PTT, the default stream to access is the public stream.  Could it be a permission in my app I need to update?

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,

John

Comment: Can you look at what is actually getting returned?  Maybe there is a useful error message in the response that would help you figure out what's going on.

Comment: Ooh I hadn't thought of that, could try and pull it out of wireshark I guess. Looking at the full stacktrace, I'm not convinced it's actually making the connection in the first place...

Comment: Agreed with @larsks. Could you please post the full stacktrace? You can use wireshark (if you are ok with it, for me it would not be easy). Else, you could download the library from sixohsix. I've taken a quick look and I'd bet your error would be at `twitter/stream.py` line 179 `json_data = json_decoder.decode(unicode_data)` (that's why the stacktrace would help).